# Calling custom profile fields?

Tags: custom-field, profiles

I've hidden and created various profile fields using the following code:

```
function my_user_contactmethods($user_contactmethods) {

// You can get rid of ones you don't want
unset($user_contactmethods['jabber']);
unset($user_contactmethods['yim']);
unset($user_contactmethods['aim']);
unset($user_contactmethods['googleplus']);
unset($user_contactmethods['url']);
unset($user_contactmethods['twitter']);

// And add any news ones. The array key is the meta key name, the text
// is however you want it labelled -- keep the key name the same as you have in gf map.

$user_contactmethods['I work for...'] = __('I work for...');

// etc for each field you want to appear

return $user_contactmethods;

}

add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'my_user_contactmethods');
```

I'm then trying to call the custom field using the following:

```
<?php echo get_user_meta($current_user->ID,'I work for...',true);?>
```

This doesn't show anything, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use Advanced Custom Fields plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try instead

```
$user_contactmethods['work'] = __('I work for...');
```

and

```
<?php echo get_user_meta($current_user->ID,'work',true);?>
```

where the array index is `'work'` instead of `'I work for...'`, i.e. lowercase and without any spaces.

Comment: I've just tried that, the info is getting inserted into the custom field but it still won't show on the front end. Is there another way to call it?

Comment: It works on my vanilla wp install, I just tested it. I checked the profile.php page for the current user, and inserted some value and saved it. Then added the code on single.php to test.

Comment: does this work for you: `<?php echo "current userid:". $current_user->ID;?>`

Comment: It's in the header.php file, so outside of the loop, that's probably why it's not working.

Comment: ok add  `global $current_user;` before the code.